# How can I use a class from vendor folder in laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I am trying to include guzzle http client from a vendor folder and using composer. Here is what I have tried so far.

Location of guzzle http client file `vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Client.php`

In composer.json file I included

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "files":["vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Client.php"],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
```

The I ran the command `composer dumpautoload`.

In my controller I am trying to call an api end point like this

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
$client = new Client(); // this line gives error 
$res = $client->get('https://api.fixer.io/latest?symbols=CZK,EURO');
```

The error is `Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found`

What I am missing here, please help me. Thanks.

**For a better file structure here is a screenshot of of the file location**
[image]

Comment: You shouldn't need to add it to your composer.json. Did you run `composer dumpautoload`

Comment: did you register the package in config/app.php

Comment: @RahulReghunath no I didn't.

Comment: @aynber, yes I ran this command.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short Version: You're trying to instantiate a class that doesn't exist.  Instantiate the right class and you'll be all set.

Long Version: You shouldn't need to do anything fancy with your composer.json to get Guzzle working.  Guzzle adheres to a the PSR standard for autoloading, which means so long as Guzzle's pulled in via composer, you can instantiate Guzzle classes without worrying about autoloading.

Based on the file path you mentioned, it sounds [like you're using Guzzle 3](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/v3.8.1).  Looking specifically at [the class you're trying to include](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/v3.8.1/src/Guzzle/Http/Client.php)

```
namespace Guzzle\Http;
/*...*/
class Client extends AbstractHasDispatcher implements ClientInterface
{
        /*...*/
}
```

The guzzle client class in Guzzle 3 is not `GuzzleHttp\Client`.  Its name is `Guzzle\Http\Client`.  So try either

```
$client = new \Guzzle\Http\Client;
```

or

```
use Guzzle\Http\Client;
$client = new Client;
```

and you should be all set.

Comment: Thank you :) It works and thanks for the explanations!