# How Can I use php Packages in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am using composer to install php packages. All packages are installed in Vendor folder. Some kind of package are easy to use in laravel but their are many php 3rd party package. Sometimes I need them to use in my laravel package.

My question is. **How can I call php package from vendor folder to my laravel controller?** If I can call them then I can use them. So I don't know how to call in laravel. But on my Row PHP project I can call them using autoloader.php But i don't understand how to call in laravel.

So please help me to use 3rd party php package/library in laravel.

Comment: What do you mean by "call php package"? What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Can You check the question again? I have clearly mentioned that I want to call PHP class from vendor folder.

Comment: Please answer my question - what does that mean? Is there any code involved that throws an error message?

Comment: When I call the PHP class from my controller then it's show that the class is not exists on the controller folder. It's the error I have faced.

Comment: Please add the code that triggers that problem to your question

Comment: Do you ever used Laravel?

Comment: I am new in Laravel that's the why I have many confusion. You mentioned that the question is not clear but other guy already answered my question. Only causes of you I can't put question in this website. What do you actually want?

Comment: The question you asked above: What do you mean by "call php package"? What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer are:
1) PHP Package: https://packagist.org/
2) I have tried call php class from vendor folder to my laravel controller class
3) I stuck when I call the class from my laravel controller it's show the error that in this controller folder the class you called is not exists

Do you want something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the package is inside the Vendor folder then in your controller function, call like this

```
$client = new \Package\Name\Class;
```

or

```
use Package\Name\Class;
$client = new Class;
```

Here is another reference
[How can I use a class from vendor folder in laravel project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48012987/how-can-i-use-a-class-from-vendor-folder-in-laravel-project?rq=1)